# How do you constrain a composite key that has a large number of non-unique combinations?

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, data-modeling

So given a table structure that looks something like this:

```
 Order_date DATE
 Order_id   NUMBER
 State      VARCHAR2(16)
 ...
 other properties/attributes
```

Keep in mind that I could use a sequence of integers here and generate a PK, however that does not interest me because of how I use this table in the main application.

So the composite key is made of Order_date, Order_id and State. The problem with this combination is that it's not necessary to be unique, but it is constrained in a way.

Ex:

```
Order_date  |  Order_id  |  State
21-09-2014     7218821      Pending
22-09-2014     2771272      Pending
20-09-2014     3277127      Approved
13-08-2014     2218765      Done
13-08-2014     2218765      Cancelled
```

Constraints:

- There is no way for one combination of the same order_date and
  order_id and state Done to be duplicated in this
- There can be any number of the same order_date and order_id with any other state than Done
- You cannot add a record with state DONE or ERROR
- You cannot skip from one state to another by bypassing their natural sequence (REGISTERED -> PENDING -> APPROVED -> DONE | CANCELLED | ERROR)

What whould be the best way for me to implement these constraints for a Oracle database?

Comment: I would muse as to whether the business rules should be implemented as constraints

Comment: Why not? It's a way for me to separate the application logic from some basic, known constraints. It's good for testing.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what entity this table represents. Is it changes to the status of an order? Or do customers add additional instructions to an order on different dates, and the status of each addition is tracked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is handled by a primary key or unique key.

The second is tricky.  The second can be handled with a function-based unique key, because Oracle allows multiple values for `NULL`:

```
create unique index unq_order_date_id_done on 
    orders(order, order_date, order_id, 
           (case when state = 'DONE' then state end));
```

I think the third and fourth need a trigger to prevent the value from being added.

Comment: For the first I mean the same order_id, the same order_date and state DONE.

Comment: @user3046061 . . . I understood.  The unique index only allows one state being `'DONE'` and any number of other values.

Answer (score 0):

Bullet by bullet:

- This is most likely true with no monitoring needed. Although you don't show it, the DATE field contains the time down to the second. In order to have a duplicate, the state for the same order will have to be changed twice within the same second.
- Doubtful. Unless your processing allows for multiple state changes for the same order within a second of each other.
- Your example data shows a state of DONE. How did that get there?
- Your description states that after APPROVED, the only allowed states are DONE or CANCELED or ERROR. Your example data shows an order going from DONE to CANCELED. This does not seem to be allowed. Actually, your second bullet suggests that a status of ERROR is not allowed under any circumstances.

The only way you can have duplicated (order, date) values is if status changes occur very quickly -- within the same second. OR...you truncate the time values from the date fields. This doesn't seem likely as there is no reason to be discarding such valuable information as the time a status change was recorded. You get no benefit and processing becomes more difficult: lose/lose.